# How to find the record(s) listing this record as a duplicate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the proper way to say this?

```
SourceNode.where(:duplicate_ids.include?(sn.id))
```

I want to find SourceNodes where the field duplicate_ids includes this id.

i.e.
SourceNode has a field, duplicate_ids.  Give me the SourceNodes that have THIS SourceNode's id  included in their duplicate_id field.

Using Ruby2, Rails4

Comment: Could you give some examples of `duplicate_ids`? i.e. Is it a string?

Comment: Sure!  :-)  
    [20] pry(main)> SourceNode.first.duplicate_ids
    SourceNode Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "source_nodes".* FROM "source_nodes" ORDER BY "source_nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    => [10609]
    [21] pry(main)> SourceNode.first.duplicate_ids.class
    SourceNode Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "source_nodes".* FROM "source_nodes" ORDER BY "source_nodes"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 => Array

Comment: So, it is an ActiveRecord relation rather than a database field?

Comment: No, It's a postgres database field.  SourceNode is a table, duplicate_id's is a field in the table to capture that a SourceNode came along that we already had.... we save the new SourceNode and mark it as a duplicate of the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct answer.

```
dups=SourceNode.pluck(:duplicate_ids).flatten.uniq
SourceNode.where('id in (?)', dups)
```